# Laravel Foreign key formed incorrectly

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with migrating table on my laravel app.
It always says

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `gamehosting`.`replies` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

But I don't see a problem with foreign key, here is the migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('replies');
    }
```

Btw, it's first adding this table and after that should add questions table, but error stops the migration. I set it to be first to migrate, but still same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This means that `id` on `questions` table is not an unsigned integer. `question_id` must be the same type in database as `id` on `questions` table. An other reason it may fail is because `questions` table and `replies` table don't have the same collation or the same engine.